# NP-complete impossible to solve in $O(n)$

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete

NP-complete problems are likely to be unsolvable in polynomial time (although no one proved it yet). My question is, has anybody proved that they are unsolvable in $O(n^d)$ for some concrete small $d$? Say, has anybody proved that it's impossible to solve subset sum in $O(n)$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, of course. Why did you say that?

Comment: @copper.hat So what? There's no proof that $P \not= NP$. Valentine's asking if there's a *known* $d$ s.t. no NPC problem can be solved in $O(n^d)$.

Comment: @user3491648: I completely missed the point. Cleaning up...

Comment: Related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17578/best-known-deterministic-time-complexity-lower-bound-for-a-natural-problem-in-np.

Comment: You would prove a $\Omega(n^d)$ lower bound for an NP-complete program.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that somebody had proved it for $O(n^d)$. Now assume $P = NP$ and fix some $NP$-complete problem that has a $O(n^r)$-time solution with $r > d$. If you pad the input of every instance, raising input length from $k$ to $k^{r/d}$ then the original algorithm works but the solution is produced in time $O((n^r)^{d/r}) = O(n^d)$, a contradiction.

In short: no. A proof that no $NP$-complete problem can have a $O(n^d)$-time solution is a proof that $P \neq NP$.

Edit: The link in zarathustra's comment frames your question in a way that avoids this kind of cheap padding trick.

Comment: How did you go from an input length of $k^{r/d}$ to an exponent of $d/r$?

Comment: The exponent $d/r$ is the $r/d$-th root.

Another way to see it: Something that is the $r$-th power of $k$ is only the $d$-th power of $k^{r/d}$.

Comment: Yes, but why would you take a root? You have an input of length $k^{r/d}$, and an $O(n^r)$ algorithm. The running time would be $O((k^{r/d})^r) = O(k^{2r/d})$.

Comment: No, the point is that the same algorithm can be modified to ignore all data after some marker to indicate that the padding begins. That doesn't change the fact that your input is length $k^{r/d}$ rather than length $k$. The algorithm still runs in time $k^r$ which, *relative to the size of the input* $n=k^{r/d}$, is $n^d$.